# Old version of site is appearing

Tags: browser, dns, cdn

Older version of site is appearing on some computers but at the same time I can able to see the new version of site.
I have done with the clearing of cookies and caches. But problem still occurs.
Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait untill all DNS servers will update their domain records - it's called [DNS propagation time](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1746/what-factors-affect-dns-propagation-time).

Some computers use different DNS servers (internet provider's, Google's, the nearest one), and it takes some time to update them all, as they are csheduled to update in different time.

Usually it's done within 24-48 hours. It may take longer sometimes, but usually it's done in no more than 6.